# CKEditor CDN Using local plugin reverts to original textrea

Tags: ckeditor, cdn

After I add the wordcount plugin it just reverts back to my orignal text area.

Here is the code I have (js is not my thing by any means):

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" maxlength="10" placeholder="5000 Characters Max.(with HTML)"></textarea>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'wordcount', '/ckeditor/plugins/wordcount/');
        config.wordcount = {
            // Whether or not you want to show the Word Count
            showWordCount: true,

            // Whether or not you want to show the Char Count
            showCharCount: false,

            // Maximum allowed Word Count
            maxWordCount: 4,

            // Maximum allowed Char Count
            maxCharCount: 10
        };

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins: 'colorbutton,colordialog,font,wordcount',
    toolbar: [
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language' ] },
        { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
        { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
        ]
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: You're breaking JavaScript because `config` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Your `config` variable (which is undefined) doesn't do anything. You need to set your configuration either in object passed to `CKEDITOR.replace` or in your `config.js` file. For more details see [Setting CKEditor Configuration](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration) guide.

Here the easiest way would be to add wordcount plugin config to the `CKEDITOR.replace` call, like so:

```
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" maxlength="10" placeholder="5000 Characters Max.(with HTML)"></textarea>
<script>
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'wordcount', '../../plug/wordcount/');

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins: 'colorbutton,colordialog,font,wordcount',
    toolbar: [
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language' ] },
        { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
        { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
    ],
    wordcount: {
        // Whether or not you want to show the Word Count
        showWordCount: true,

        // Whether or not you want to show the Char Count
        showCharCount: false,

        // Maximum allowed Word Count
        maxWordCount: 4,

        // Maximum allowed Char Count
        maxCharCount: 10
    }
} );
</script>
```

Comment: This would work if you are using a local version but I was using the CDN, which usues no local config file unless defined but there is no really clear documentation as to how to do that. Bits and pieces only. I have abandoned CKeditor anyways though. The lack of documentation there is for the CDN is appalling and there are no clear breaks between documentation of versions....

Comment: I don't see any reason why above code wouldn't work with CDN. It's inlined config, it's [clearly explained in docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration-section-defining-configuration-in-page). The only requirement on your side is to add `wordcount` plugin in `../../plug/wordcount/` directory. Without that, well, you can't add plugin without plugin code.

Comment: You don't see any reason why it wouldn't work, yet it didn't. CK is to much hassle and not enough real world(non JS developer) user friendly.